# Thermal relief pads with through holes shall be soldered on top and bottom

Tags: pcb-assembly

I would like to know what is the right and correct process for Thermal relief pads for double component sides PCBA.

1. Should the Thermal relief pad fill with solder on the opposite side of the components?
2. If solder fillet is done from second side (as being requested) creates a reliability problem by entrapping flux inside the vias. This flux is highly corrosive & will damage the PCBA & cause a failure.
3. Can those via holes and pads fill with solder paste?

[image] [image]